# Cannot get the name of a function passed as a parameter with code quotations, in F#

Tags: f#, quotations

I have a function that looks like that:

```
let rec retryAsync (retryAttempts: TimeSpan list) (request: unit -> Async<Result<'a, ExchangeError>>) : Async<Result<'a, ExchangeError>> = ....
```

and, upon an error I would like to print the name of the function passed as '*request*'. It has this signature:

```
unit -> Async<Result<'a, ExchangeError>>
```

I thought about using something like this (slightly modified version of code I found online):

```
module DocumentGetter =
    let GetName ([<ReflectedDefinition>]x:Expr<_->_>) =
        match x with
        | DerivedPatterns.Lambdas(_, Patterns.Call(_,methodInfo,_)) ->
            methodInfo.Name
        | _ -> "unknown"
```

but then I get this compile error:

> [FS0001] The type 'unit -> Async<Result<'a,ExchangeError>>' is not compatible with the type 'Quotations.Expr<('b -> 'c)>'

If I pass the main function (retryAsync), I can get the name out, but I can't get the name of the function passed to it. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit conversion to F# quotations based on the `ReflectedDefinition` attribute does not work for let-bound functions, but only for static members. The following works as expected:

```
type DocumentGetter =
  static member GetName ([<ReflectedDefinition>]x:Expr<_->_>) =
      match x with
      | DerivedPatterns.Lambdas(_, Patterns.Call(_,methodInfo,_)) ->
          methodInfo.Name
      | _ -> "unknown"

let rec retryAsync (retryAttempts: TimeSpan list) 
  (request: unit -> Async<Result<'a, ExchangeError>>) 
    : Async<Result<'a, ExchangeError>> = failwith "!"

DocumentGetter.GetName retryAsync
```

That said, I'm not quite sure what your scenario for this is. It sounds like you are trying to do something pretty complicated - I think there might be an easier way to solve your actual problem without doing this.

Comment: here's the scenario: I have a bunch of functions doing rest calls to a crypto exchange. They all return async<result<'a, ExchangeError>>. I have then another function that is a retry loop and it takes any of these functions as a parameter and will loop with a delay if the call needs to be retried. But, in the retry function, I don't know the name of what is called (which rest function), so for logging I would like to extract the name

Comment: I guess tht makes sense - though I would probably just pass a string with a name as an extra parameter, because it does not sound like something you need to do too often.

Comment: yes, it's simpler; I was just hoping there would be an easy way with this :)

Comment: The reason there is no "straightforward" way to do this is that not every function has a name. Consider `retryAsync [] (fun () -> AsyncResult.Return 42)`. I would recommend representing these REST calls as something more complicated than just a function.